# Cannot access href from a element

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I cannot select an href with Mechanize. I have done so successfully in the past with the following methods, but for this website it does not seem to work. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is a snippet of the output of just the selector:

```
<div class="component-user-name component-user-name-15">
<a class="name-page-link" data-reco-action="view"   
href="/profile/name">Name</a>
```

These are my attempts:

```
agent.page.search(".selector a").map {|link| link["href"]}
agent.page.search(".selector a["href"]")
agent.page.search(".selector a")[0]["href"]
agent.page.search(".selector a").attribute["href"]
```

Comment: At present, does your code still work with the other sites that it used to, and does not work particularly with certain websites?

Comment: I am not sure how mechanize works, but could it be that some DOM elements on the page are created with JavaScript, and cannot be detected by mechanize? If that is the case, a solution may be to download the html as well as the scripts from the website, and reproduce the web page on a headless browser, like selenium.

Comment: The code works for other websites

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking, we expect a code example that works and demonstrates the problem. Without that we're forced to write something, probably unrelated to what you're using, to try to simulate the problem. That wastes our time and introduces some wobble into the solutions we come up with. Please read "[ask]", including the links at the bottom, and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 0):

Try this (html is different, you cannot do copy&paste from different website ;) ):

```
agent.page.search('a.name-page-link').attribute('href')
```

Answer (score 0):

If it really looks like that, then:

```
agent.page.at("a.name-page-link")["href"]
```